# Get JSON response not working on mobile device with Ionic framework and jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using the following script to get a JSON response from my server and append a HTML element in my mobile app.

I am using the Ionic framework but ideally would like to build using jQuery instead of the AngularJS modules (although I may have to just lump it and learn them).

The script works fine on the web but when I test it on my Nexus 5 there is no joy and the table cells aren't printed out.

**HTML**

```
<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="header bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">GeoSnap</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
      <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
      </table>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

**jQuery code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.getJSON("http://webdevdanno.com/php-services/DataHandler.php", function(records) {
    var recordsHTML = ''; 
    for(var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
        var name = records[i].heading;
        var description = records[i].desc;
        recordsHTML += '<tr>' + '<td>' + name + '</td>' + '<td>' + description + '</td>' + '</tr>';
    }
    angular.element("tbody").html(recordsHTML);
});
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this wouldn't print out the table records when I build it onto my mobile device?

Is there a way in AngularJS I can achieve the JSON request functionality?

Comment: if you have angular in page this approach is really wrong. Should be using the data model to drive the view. In this case `ng-repeat` based on passing response to controller would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use cordova, you need to whitelist the url's you want to use in your config.xml like this. (Also see cordova whitelisting)

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://somesite.com/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://somesite.com/*" />
```

Comment: I've put that into my config.xml file but no luck currently! =[

Comment: Yes. Done. My current cordova platforms are listed as just ios in package.json Should there be an android one as well?